# Right Click Drag with Magic Trackpad

Tags: multi-touch, magic-trackpad

Is it possible to perform a "right click drag" with a Magic Trackpad?  What gestures/settings do I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have the same problem sharing magic tracpad using synergy.  When you tap down with two fingers and lift its a right click, two fingers and hold its a scroll.
What works is two fingers, then press down hard enough to engage the physical mouse button built into the feet.*

This works, but... the problem is that you can't do locked drags this way; i.e., with a USB or wireless mouse, you can right drag by pressing the right mouse button, and if you run out of mousing space, you can pick the mouse literally off the surface and as long as you continue to hold down the right button, you can continue to drag by repositioning the mouse at a different location on the surface .

Similarly, you can do locked drags with the trackpad by momentarily picking your fingers up off the surface and by repositioning them quickly enough, you can continue the drag, ad infinitum.

But if you right drag using the above described method with the trackpad, as soon as you release the pressure from the trackpad button, it springs up and the Windows VM immediately at that spot presents you with the right drag context sensitive menu.

It would work much better if you could produce the right drag by holding down a key such as Ctrl, Option, etc., with your second hand while performing a normal three-finger drag on the trackpad with your first hand. But contrary to the next most recent answer, this does not produce a right drag action in Windows.

***Feb 2015/Windows 7 in Parallels 10 in Yosemite/ I've found sequence Ctrl+Shift, then 3 finger drag then lift off trackpad THEN release Ctrl+Shift works for me (in Audition 1.0/Frequency Analysis adjusting horizontal scale)***

Answer (score 3):

I don't like pressing hard to drag, I use the 3-finger-drag gesture. With this it is easy to right-drag, just hold `ctrl` on the keyboard and drag with three fingers on the Trackpad.

Comment: This is exactly how I'd do it

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 under Parallels I can right-drag with the Magic Trackpad by clicking and dragging with two fingers. I can also click with two fingers and continue dragging with one to get a right drag. I don't think OSX has a right-drag.